# finite Kolmogorov space, locally closed subsets

Tags: general-topology

In the notes on Adic Spaces of Wedhorn

https://www2.math.uni-paderborn.de/fileadmin/Mathematik/People/wedhorn/Lehre/AdicSpaces.pdf

I have just read the statement that every subset of a finite Kolmogorov space is locally closed (prop 3.19, part 2 of the proof).

It seems to me that the set $X = \{a,b,c\}$ consisting of three points equipped with the topology whose closed subsets are given by $\{\emptyset,\{a\},\{a,b\}, X\}$ provides a counterexample (the subset $S = \{a,c\}$ of $X$ is not locally closed).

Is this a small mistake or am I missing something? Thanks in advance.

Comment: It seems to me that your example is correct. Of course, the set $\{a,c\}$ is constructible, so it's not a counterexample to the proposition, just to its proof.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your counterexample to the proof is correct. The proposition is still true:

If $x \in X$, where $X$ is a finite Kolmogorov ($T_0$) space and $y \neq x$, then either there is an open subset $O$ that contains $x$ and not $y$, or there is a closed subset that contains $x$ and not $y$. The open subset is by definition constructible (open and (quasi-) compact, being finite), and a closed set also is, as its complement is open and (quasi-) compact.

So for every $x, y, y \neq x$ we have a constructible set $F(x,y)$ such that $x \in F(x,y), y \notin F(x,y)$.

Now, $\{x\} = \cap_{y \neq x} F(x,y)$ which is a finite intersection of constructible sets so also constructible. It follows that all subsets of a finite Kolmogorov space are constructible.